# JQuery how to get the button id of native 'save' button on record

Tags: jquery, netsuite, suitescript2.0

In a client script, I am trying to add the following:

jQuery('#button_submitter').click();

This is supposed to refer to the native Netsuite save button on a Journal record.

I have tried looking online though can't find any examples of how to use Jquery with Suitescript.
[image: inspectelement]

Based on the screenshot, have I referenced the button correctly?

Edit:Thanks for the suggestion Dori Rina...

I am getting the following error message though when I try that code
[image: error message]

Comment: `submitter` is the id of button, not `button_submitter`. So, jQuery('#submitter').click(); may work.

Comment: I tried jQuery('#submitter').click() and it didn't work

Comment: Check console and look for errors.  May be the element you are trying to access is not in html yet and gets rendered after you run jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Jashwant.

I tested it in the console and it finally worked

For my script though, is there a way to specify that the jQuery button only takes effect after another process has finished running?

e.g. after the page has redirected to another url and the new page is in the browser?

Comment: ask another question regarding new problem

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one input type="submit" you can use the following code to get the button id:

```
let btnId = $('input[type=submit]').attr('id');
```

Or you can use input name selector:

```
let btnId = $('input[name=submitter]').attr('id');
```